# Send SSH commands from iOS?

Tags: objective-c

The app I am planning to develop involves sending SSH commands from the phone to a server that supports SSH. Is there a library that will help me connect and send commands to an SSH server?
Thanks! I looked at libssh, but a lot of the stuff it used was deprecated in iOS6. 
~Carpetfizz

Answer (score 9):

NMSSH works great! I was able to successfully implement this into an iOS project, and get everything to work.

https://github.com/Lejdborg/NMSSH

Comment: NMSSH is so godly, so easy!

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [this](http://home.comcast.net/~seiryu/libcurl-ios.html): I expect you'd still need to do a non-trivial bit of work to make it fit into your app, but that should work.

Comment: Thanks, but according to the site itself: _The SSH, SFTP, and SCP protocols. libcurl relies on libssh2 to use SSH protocols, and libssh2 relies on either GnuPG or OpenSSL to do its cryptography work. iOS ships with neither library, and porting libssh2 to Apple's cryptography libraries is complicated by the fact that Apple's cryptography libraries don't contain public interfaces for arbitrarily big number computing as of iOS 6._

Comment: Ah, odd. I've seen http://atastypixel.com/blog/easy-inclusion-of-openssl-into-iphone-app-projects/ in the past that makes OpenSSL integration a bit more straightforward. Maybe you can try that?

Comment: Thanks, but I managed to find a library that worked well for me: https://github.com/Lejdborg/NMSSH